# Restarting Activity doesnt kill old activity entirely?

Tags: java, android-layout, android-activity, onresume

Every time my app enters pAUSE stage and enters  onresumestage, i am  killing my current activity and start new Acitivy. And at the same time in onresume stage, i try to make some button visible. Some how the visibility function never gets updated. Always stays at defualt invisible stage...   any help highly appreciated. ..

// code in onresume stage that makes button ready visible and at the same time call refresh function

```
public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        refresh();

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    ImageButton ready = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ready);
                    ready.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            });
            
      }
```

// thats where i am killing current activity and starting new activity

```
public void refresh() {


    Intent intent = getIntent();
    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
   // MediaPresentationActivity.this.finish();

    finish();
    recreate();
    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

// xml image button set default visibility to invisible

```
 <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ready"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
      
        android:visibility="invisible"

         />
```

Answer (score 0):

From the best of my knowledge , refreshing activity kill the current activity. Only issue could be onResume function. You should try java Synchronous function. Currently setvisbility for image button is executed before finishing the refresh function . Actually it does set image button to visible, but refresh function will delete it as both run at the same time. so you should try Synchronous function : which allow second function to call ,only after first function is executed completely.

Answer (score 0):

what simply you can do is calling the same activity again like

```
Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

**Note:** Replace MainActivity with your own class name.